# misnamed viewcontroller

Tags: xcode

All my classes are prefixed automatically by "BS". Two of my view controllers in the storyboard seem to be prefixed only by "S". I cannot tell if that is a problem, but I would like to change it, if it could be a problem. In the image is the incorrect name in the scene dock as well as in the objects utility list. [image: In the image is the incorrect name in the scene dock as well as in the objects utility list]

Answer (score 1):

You can pick any name for your VCs as long as you use that name in your code.

To change the name of a class, click on the name of your class in your @implementation line:

```
@implementation classNameClickOnMe
```

and then Edit > Refactor > Rename

Save a snapshot just in case. The only place where the class name will not be updated, is in the comment section on top of the .m and .h file, you will have to change them manually.

Comment: I think my classes are all correctly named with the BS prefix. I cannot understand how the VC's are sort of double named. For example, the header has `Ssetup View Controller - BSdealViewControllerScene`. Where does that first part come from? I cannot see it anywhere to try to change it. AFAIK my code says BSsetupViewController everywhere. Notice spaces in the first part of the header, btw.